# Cordova android app - POST request returns "forbidden access" error

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, post

For some reason my Cordova built app cannot send POST requests as a mobile application. If I run it from a browser (in my PC or mobile device) it works fine, but when I run it as mobile app request fails giving 403 forbidden error. Maybe someone has encountered similar problem before and knows what to do?

P.S. GET requests work fine.

config.xml:

```
<access origin="mytestserver.eu/test"/>
```

.js:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://mytestserver.eu/test",
    data: '{ "test": "Test"}',
    dataType:'json',
    headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert ($.toJSON(data));
   },
   error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert ($.toJSON(errorThrown));
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved when I **disabled ModSecurity** on my server.

For me, I was able to do that via the cPanel access to my host:

cPanel > Security > ModSecurity

Comment: could you provide an example on how to do same type of request using cordova plugin ?Thanks in advance.